# Iptables forward connection timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, iptables, amazon-vpc

I am gonna connect to Oracle Database which is located on Server2-OracleDB from Server3. Server1-Proxy and Server3 are in AWS and in different VPC network but the VPCs have been peered and they have access to each other using private IP. Server2-OracleDB is located in an external network and I have access to it by VPN connection between Server1-Proxy and Server2-OracleDB.

[image]

So only Server1-Proxy has access to external Oracle-DB server. Now I need to get access to OracleDB from Server3. What I wanted to do is using iptables forwarding to made this access happen.

My Iptables rules look like below in Server1-Proxy:

Server3 IP: 172.28.201.230, Server1-Proxy IP:172.28.205.10 , Server2-OracleDB IP:10.130.180.230

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s 172.28.201.230 --dport 1521 -j DNAT --to 10.130.180.230
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.130.180.230 -p tcp --sport 1521 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.130.180.230 -p tcp --dport 1521 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.130.180.230 -p tcp --sport 1024:65535 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -j MASQUERADE
```

When I try telnet from Server3 to Server2-OracleDB it gives me Connetion-Time out and when I check the flow logs in Server3 network I can just see this:

```
2 myaccount-id myinterface-id 172.28.201.230 10.130.189.230 49864 1521 6 7 420 1533815087 1533815207 ACCEPT OK
```

It seems that I don't get answer from OracleDB server and I guess there is something wrong in iptables setup.

The ip_forward is enabled and the routing table and security-group look correct.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in iptables but i think you need to masquerade your rule not just doing DNAT. If you do DNAT Server 2 should have routing for server 3 network.
If you want you can try something like this on server 1 :

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 1521 -j MASQUERADE
alternatively you can specify source ip:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 1521 -s 172.28.205.10 -j MASQUERADE
```

in bothe rules you should specify route for server2 network like:

```
route add -net 10.130.180.230/24 gw  172.28.205.10
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've tried it however it still doesn't work.